# What does 'default' keyword mean with css variables?

Tags: css

I've come across following syntax:

```
border-color: var(--disabled) default;
```

which is not correctly interpreted by my css minifier (it believes it is alternating colors - top-bottom & left-right).

Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation on the css feature.
Can anyone point me to the feature name / documentation?

See it in action (I tested it on Chrome):

```css
:root {
    --disabled: #0000DD;
}

.status-parent {
    color: red;
}

.status {
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--disabled) default;
}
```

```html
<p class="status-parent">
    <span class="status">I have red border</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Not to be picky, but maybe you want to know: Wouldn't it be "disabled" instead of "dissabled"?

Comment: Where did you come across it? Are you sure *they* got it correct?

Comment: default in this context has nothing to do with the variable, it's trying to set one of the border sides colour to 'default' which isn't a colour so the property is failing and inheriting the red colour from its parent.

Comment: `border-color` does not have a default value.

Comment: @dantheman93 I am happy to accept it as a correct answer. I was mislead by the fact that Chrome does not flag `var(--disabled) default` as an invalid value (`default` is indeed marked as invalid). Now I check I can add any rubbish `var(--dissabled) invalidvalue` and it is does not apply the rule, but it does not flag it as invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border-color` does [not have a *default* value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-color). Therefore this rule is ignored by the browser.

There is no problem with your CSS Variables. Below is the same code with `default` replaced by `yellow` :

```css
:root {
    --dissabled: #0000DD;
}

.status-parent {
    color: red;
}

.status {
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: var(--dissabled) yellow;
    padding:0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<p class="status-parent">
    <span class="status">I have red border</span>
</p>
```

Because the CSS specifity of `.status` overrides the parent `color` for the border you will see that the variable (blue) does the top- and bottom- and the second argument yellow does the left- and right- borders.

Comment: Thanks, as noted in question, I was mislead by the tooling - `var(--disabled) default` is not marked in Chrome as invalid syntax(while `default` is) - I incorrectly supposed it must be some feature of CSS variables.

Comment: @Lesiak to be honest, CSS variables seem not fully comfortable in the CSS programming frame, they're also comparatively rare.